# using csvsimple, how do I put a line under the header?

Tags: csvsimple

I can make a simple table like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{words.csv}
num, word
1, apple
2, dog
3, pizza
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
\bfseries Num & \bfseries Text 
\csvreader[head to column names]{words.csv}{}{\\\num & \word}
\\\hline
\end
{tabular}

\end{document}
```

but when I try to add a line underneath the header like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{words.csv}
num, word
1, apple
2, dog
3, pizza
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
\bfseries Num & \bfseries Text 
\hline
\csvreader[head to column names]{words.csv}{}{\\\num & \word}
\\\hline
\end
{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
./csv-simple-error.tex:16: Misplaced \noalign.
\hline ->\noalign 
              {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule \@height \arrayrulewidth \futurelet...
 l.16 \hline
```

What does the error mean?  and how can I add a horizontal line under the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\hline` can only appear immediately after the format declaration or after a line change command `\\`; since this is not the case for the first `\hline` in your example code, and error is triggered. Here's one possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{words.csv}
num, word
1, apple
2, dog
3, pizza
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
\bfseries Num & \bfseries Text  \\
\hline
\csvreader[head to column names]{words.csv}{}{\num & \word\\}
\\[-\normalbaselineskip]\hline
\end
{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `late after line`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
num, word
1, apple
2, dog
3, pizza
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cl}
\bfseries Num & \bfseries Text \\ \hline
\csvreader[
  head to column names,
  late after line=\\,
]{\jobname.csv}{}{\num & \word}
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The alternative way is to use the `tabular` option to `\csvreader`, which implies `\\` at the end of rows:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
num, word
1, apple
2, dog
3, pizza
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
  tabular=cl,
  head to column names,
  table head=\bfseries Num & \bfseries Text \\ \hline,
  table foot=\hline,
]{\jobname.csv}{}{\num & \word}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the documentation says "Note that table options like /csv/tabular→ P. 16 set this key to \\ automatically" http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf -- confused as to why we need to set it explicitly in this case.

Comment: @Ultrasaurus You're not using the `tabular` option to `\csvreader`. I added the alternative input style.

Comment: if tabular=cl isn't the tabular option, what is?